# Concatenating strings Zybooks Lab 2.1.2

Tags: string-concatenation

Write two statements to read in values for my_city followed by my_state. Do not provide a
prompt. Assign log_entry with current_time, my_city, and my_state. Values should be separated
by a space. Sample output for given program if my_city is Houston and my_state is Texas:
2014-07-26 02:12:18: Houston Texas
Note: Do not write a prompt for the input values.

```
current_time = '2014-07-26 02:12:18:'
my_city = ''
my_state = ''
log_entry =

''' Your solution goes here '''

print(log_entry)
```

I've tried several solutions and it is only printing out the date and time. Since the date and
time is given, I figured to concatenate the city and state strings then add them under log
entry however it still only prints out the date. I can't enter the actual city and state
because there is a back end test where Zybooks add a different city and state. Here is what I
have tried so far.

```
concatenated_string = my_city + ' ' + my_state
log_entry = current_time + concatenated_string
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually figured it out.

```
my_city = input("")
my_state = input("")
log_entry = (current_time + ' ' + my_city + ' ' + my_state)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
current_time = '2014-07-26 02:12:18:'
my_city = ''
my_state = ''
log_entry = ''

my_city = input()
my_state = input()
log_entry = current_time + ' ' + my_city + ' ' + my_state

print(log_entry)
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Always include explanations.